# Streamlit map occupying the entire background

Tags: python, maps, streamlit

I'm currently building an application with Streamlit and I'd like to plot a map which fills the entire background. Is there a way to do so in Streamlit? I have following code:

```
import streamlit as st
import folium 
from streamlit_folium import folium_static

m = folium.Map(location=[-22.908333, -43.196389], zoom_start=11, tiles='OpenStreetMap')
folium_static(m)
```

But the generated map does not fill all the browser available space. I'd like to fill the browser available space like in the example below

Example that I found on the internet:
[image: Example]

Comment: Do you want your whole application to look like that? With widgets on the left side and widgets on the right?

Answer (score 2):

You can set your Streamlit app to use wide mode with `st.set_page_config(layout="wide")`.

It needs to be the first streamlit call you make (i.e. first thing you do after importing streamlit). This will allow you to make use of the whole screen.

```
import streamlit as st
import folium 
from streamlit_folium import folium_static

st.set_page_config(layout="wide")

m = folium.Map(location=[-22.908333, -43.196389], zoom_start=11, tiles='OpenStreetMap')
folium_static(m)
```

And I don't know about the `streamlit_folium`, you may need to increase the plot size